# Traer datos en dataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio

esta es la estructura de mi proyecto

**Proyecto DataAccess**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**clase ConnectionToSql**
acá esta mi conexión a la bd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public  abstract  class ConnectionToSql
    {
        private readonly string connectionString;
        public ConnectionToSql()  {
            connectionString = "Server=******; Password=*******; user=sa; DataBase=Tareas";

        }
        protected SqlConnection GetConnection() {
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

**classe UserDao**  en esta clase llamo los procedimientos o las consultas pero al traer el procedimiento ListarProyectos no me lo trae en el data dataGridView 
no se muy bien en que capa poner el código para que esta me traiga los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Common.Cache;
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class UserDao: ConnectionToSql
    {
        public bool Login(string user, string pass)
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection()) {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand()) {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "select *from Users where LoginName=@user and Password=@pass";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) {
                            UserLoginCache.IdUser = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            UserLoginCache.FirstName = reader.GetString(3);
                            UserLoginCache.LastName = reader.GetString(4);
                            UserLoginCache.Position = reader.GetString(5);
                            UserLoginCache.Email = reader.GetString(6);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        public DataTable ListarProyectos()
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "ListarProyectos";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    Tabla.Load(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                    return Tabla;
                   }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Proyecto Domain**

**Classe UserModel**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DataAccess;

namespace Domain
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        public bool LoginUser(string user, string pass) {
            return userDao.Login(user, pass);
        }
    }
}
```

**Proyecto Presentation**

desde el formulario FormProyecto estoy llamando el procedimiento ListarProyecto
pero no me trae nada en el dataGridView en que capa tiene que ir el código o que estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using DataAccess;

    namespace ProyectoTareas
    {
        public partial class FormProyectos : Form
        {
            public FormProyectos()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void FormProyectos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ListarProyectos();
            }

            private void ListarProyectos()
            {
                UserDao objtarea = new UserDao();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = objtarea.ListarProyectos();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Si ejecutas el procedure desde el Management Studio, este retorna registros ?

Comment: Si señor, si me arroja resultados

Comment: Me puedes ayudar ¿?

Comment: agrega un try catch al metodo ListarProyectos() y dinos cual es la excepcion si es que la hay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proba asi en tu metodo Listar Proyectos

```
 public DataTable ListarProyectos()
 {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      using (var connection = GetConnection())
      {
        connection.Open();
        //Indico el SP que voy a utilizar
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ListarProyectos", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        //Aquí ejecuto el SP y lo lleno en el DataTable
        adapter.Fill(dt);


      }
     return dt;
}
```